# Convergence of the sum implies convergence of the summands?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Given  a  sequence $\{g_{n}\}$  of Lebesgue  measurable  functions such  that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{I}|g_{n}|$ is convergent, then does that mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{I}g_{n}^{+}$  and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{I}g^{-}_{n}$  are  also  convergent? Here $f^{+}=\max(f,0)$  and  $f^{-}=\max(-f,0)$.

I am  trying  to  prove  something  which  will  be  done  if  I  have  got  this  point  right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes** since
$$
g_{n}^{-}\leq |g_n|,\qquad g_{n}^{+}\leq |g_n|.
$$